# Why Gulp doesn't create css file?

Tags: sass, gulp

I have a problem because I've created task in gulpfiles.js but when I'm creating my file: .scss and then I write command gulp in bash. I have no errors, but there is no file in css folder. In my bash this code apeearing:

```
C:\Users\DOM\Desktop\react\my-react-project>gulp
[16:33:25] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\react\my-react-project\gulpfile.js
[16:33:25] Starting 'watch_scss'...
[16:33:25] Finished 'watch_scss' after 13 ms
[16:33:25] Starting 'default'...
[16:33:25] Finished 'default' after 12 μs
```

This is my code from gulpfile.js :

```
    'use strict';

    //dependencies
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');
    var changed = require('gulp-change');




    /////////////////////////////////
    // - SCSS/CSS
    ////////////////////////////////

   var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
   var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

   //Compile SCSS
   gulp.task('compile_scss',function () {

   gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
   .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
   });


   //Detect changes in SCSS
   gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
   gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']); 
   });


   //Run tasks
   gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

I can't find where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
var changed = require('**gulp-change**');
```

you should require gulp-changed,so this should work fine.

```
var changed = require('**gulp-changed**');
```

If you find this answer helpful please give thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

`gulp.watch` would run your task `'compile_scss'` only when you change file in dir defined in `SCSS_SRC`. Until gulp does not see any modifications in files there - `gulp.watch` would do nothing. Try `gulp.task('default', ['compile_scss', 'watch_scss']);`. And I recommend you to use `gulp-sync`plugin to make tasks `'compile_scss', 'watch_scss'` run one after another, because if you modify your default task as I've recommended - these 2 tasks would run in parallel

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I change sth in my scss file, there's no effect. My dest dir is empty. I've done what you said and I tried to: gulp.task('default', ['compile_scss', 'watch_scss']); but then I have an error: TypeError: run.call is not a function. When I run directly gulp compile_scss , I get the same error: typeError: run.call is not a function.

Comment: me either, cuz I do not see previous code anymore, so I have nothing to compare with :D

Answer (score 0):

I've changed previous code to this code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');


//var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass =   require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

var SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var DEST = './src/Assets/css/';

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(SRC)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch(SRC,['styles']);
});
```

and everything works but I have no idea why.